# Runtime Error 1004 using Select with several workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook which pulls out data from two other workbooks.
Since the data changes hourly there is the possibility that this macro is used more than one time a day for the same data.
So I just want to select all previous data to this date period and want to delete them.
Later on the data will be copied in anyway.
But as soon as I want to use

> WBSH.Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Select

the code stopes with Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.

Followed just a snippet of the code with the relevant part.
What is wrong here?

```
'Set source workbook
Dim currentWb As Workbook
Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook
Set WBSH = currentWb.Sheets("Tracking")

 'Query which data from the tracking files shoud get pulled out to the file
  CheckDate = Application.InputBox(("From which date you want to get data?" & vbCrLf &       "Format: yyyy/mm/dd "), "Tracking data", Format(Date - 1, "yyyy/mm/dd"))

    'states the last entry which is done ; know where to start ; currentWb File
With currentWb.Sheets("Tracking")
    lastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
End With

'just last 250 entries get checked since not so many entries are made in one week
j = lastRow - 250

'Check if there is already data to the look up date in the analyses sheet and if so deletes these records
Do
    j = j + 1
    'Exit Sub if there is no data to compare to prevent overflow
    If WBSH.Cells(j + 1, "C").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop While WBSH.Cells(j, "C").Value < CheckDate
If j <> lastRow - 1 Then
    'WBSH.Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Select
    'Selection.ClearContents
End If
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't use `Select` for on `Range` on a Sheet which is not selected/activated. `Select` only works on the **active** worksheet.

You should have something like

```
WBSH.Activate
```

before

```
WBSH.Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Select
```

```
WBSH.Range(WBSH.Cells(j, "A"), WBSH.Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Select
```

Take a look here: [Selecting and activating Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221576%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

*NOTE:* Avoid using Select as much as you can

**EDIT:** To clear the content (As asked in the comments), you should use someting like

```
WBSH.Range(WBSH.Cells(j, "A"), WBSH.Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Clear
```

instead of (I imagine)

```
WBSH.Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Clear
```

because the cells in your range needs to be qualified.

You can use `Clear` which deletes the formatting of the cell and the value in that cell, and `ClearContent` which deletes only the value in the cell.

Note that you can use `With`:

```
With WBSH
    .Range(.Cells(j, "A"), .Cells(lastRow - 1, "M")).Clear
End With
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I just want to select it to clear this range right away - so I tried .Clear but that doesn't work either. So is there are smarter way to clear this range? Thanks

Comment: Hey, I tried the activate before the select but is still gives out the same error..

Comment: @Johaen I edited my solution to add code which should work (not tested, sorry) to clear the cells. Note this is a different question and it sould have been asked with a new question intead of in the comments ^^

Comment: @Johaen you're right, I did a mistake, I forgot the Cells qualification (`WBSH.`) Tell me if it works now (: (and if the `Clear` part works)

Comment: Yeah. It works - thanks for the help. The tip with the select was really helpful and the mistake with forgetting to address the cells :)THANK YOU smagnan